# MySQLi Prepared statements - Wrapper function for SELECT

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I recently started using MySQLi prepared statements. I did not liked how many rows of code that was needed for just a simple select statement. So I created a wrapper function, see the code below the questions below.
Note: get_results() or PDO is not an option for me.

**My questions are:**

1. Will it slow down the performance noticeably?
2. Will it be more memory intensive because of the use of the result array?
3. Will the $stmt->close() before the return cause any problems? For example maybe the result array data is also are freed from memory?
4. Do I need to close or free anything else (except from closing the db connection)?
5. Do you see any other problems with the function or could it be improved?

**Code:**

```
class DatabaseHelper{

static function select($con, $query, $formats, $params){
    $a_params = array();

    $param_type = '';
    $n = count($formats);
    for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        $param_type .= $formats[$i];
    }

    $a_params[] = & $param_type;

    for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        $a_params[] = & $params[$i];
    }

    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $a_params);
    $stmt->execute();

    $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();
    while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
        $columns[] = &$row[$field->name];
    }

    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $columns);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        foreach($row as $key => $val) {
            $x[$key] = $val;
        }
        $results[] = $x;
    }
    $stmt->close();
    return $results;
}

}
```

**Used like this for example:**

```
$users = DatabaseHelper::select($conn, "SELECT name,username FROM users WHERE id > ?", "i", array(30));
foreach ($users as $row){
    echo $row['username'] . " ". $row['name'] . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: what is your php version?

Comment: PHP Version 5.6.27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will it slow down the performance noticeably?

No.

> Will it be more memory intensive because of the use of the result array?

No, as long as you are selecting sensible amounts of data. In a modern application you have to select all the data first anyway, as the business logic should be separated from display logic.

> Will the $stmt->close() before the return cause any problems? For example maybe the result array data is also are freed from memory?

Why not to try and see?

> Do I need to close or free anything else (except from closing the db connection)?

You rather don't have to close a statement either.

> Do you see any other problems with the function or could it be improved?

- First and foremost. As it's a class you are writing, and not a function, there is absolutely no point in passing the connection through a parameter. Make it a static property.
- Also, I would suggest to make types the last parameter with default value. In most cases you don't have to nitpick with types - a default string will do.
- Besides, as your PHP version is 5.6 you can use the splat operator just to reduce the amount of code. You can check [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35686613/285587) for the details
- I would also suggest to split your function into several methods - one to execute the query and others to get the results. It will let you to re-use the same code for all kinds of queries
- make sure you are [watching for mysqli errors as explained here](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting)

So, ideally you'd call your query this way

```
$users = DatabaseHelper::getAll("SELECT name,username FROM users WHERE id > ?", [30]);
foreach ($users as $row){
    echo $row['username'] . " ". $row['name'] . "<br />";
}
```

where getAll() method is using query() method internally to perform a query and then to fetch all the results. Similarly you may want to write getRow() and getOne() methods